# How can I push working branch to OLD existing repo?

Tags: git, push, atlassian-sourcetree

I have an old repo on git called "Website".  I changed repo and now am working on "Projects". I want to push my working branch "2017-10-25" on my old repo "Website".  How can I do this?  I'm am also using SourceTree for those who knows it.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With commandline you can add remote and then push to it.
can be done by:

`$ git remote add NAME https://github.com/REPO_URL`

Then:

`$ git push NAME LOCAL_BRANCH:REMOTE_BRANCH`

Where `REMOTE_BRANCH` is branch on your "old" remote and `LOCAL_BRANCH` is your branch on current git repo.

Check remotes by:

`$ git remote -v`

Or you can totally get control and check `.git/config` by your favorite editor :) but backup first

[Full article here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes)